# Percentage Calculation - Cells per micro litre

Tags: education, percentages, percentile

I came across this simple percentage calculation and I couldn't solve it (I couldn't prove otherwise). Here's the problem. **Find percentage for 11/0.1 ul (11 cells per 0.1 micro litre).** Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.